# Database conflicton delete

Tags: c#, sql

I cant delete my user. As im pressing delete i get the following error;

> "FK_dbo.Environments_dbo.JobExperiences_JobExperienceId". The conflict
>   occurred in database "DiplTestDb", table "dbo.Environments", column
>   'JobExperienceId'.

I assume that i get the error because the environments and jobexperience are related and therefore has to be deleted at the same time. Does anyone if this can be done through fluentAPI or is there a different solution to this.

Comment: I think cascade delete is what you are looking for.

Comment: you need to delete the record(s) containing the foreign key which relates to the main record, before you can delete the main record. You can either do that with a preliminary delete statement, or by setting cascading delete rules in your database. In your case, from the error, it sounds like to need to remove a record (or records) form the Environments table where the JobExperienceID matches the JobExperienceID of the record in JobExperiences which you wish to delete.

Comment: This is bad practice from an auditing and security perspective though

Comment: @LeoRams Would you like to elaborate? Surely that depends on whether you audit what goes on, and/or whether deleting these depdendent records is actually a necessary or desirable part of the process. Perhaps the business rule in fact should be that the record cannot be deleted while there are child records which relate to it. We don't know what the desired behaviour actually is, all we've got is an error message with a request for a technical solution.

Answer (score 2):

The specific reason you are getting the exception is, as you correctly assume, that there is a foreign key link between user, and Environments.experienceId (from now on experience).

To do a hard delete as you request, you would need to delete the experience rows that have a foreign key relation to user.

Say you wish to delete user: id 1, userEmail, test@useremail.com

Pseudo Code:

```
DbContext context = new DbContext();
User forDeletion = context.Users.FirstOrDefault(x => x.id == 1);
context.Environments.Delete(x => x.User_Id == forDeletion.id);
context.SaveChanges();
```

However, I would seriously recommend you not do this. 
You should instead add a column on the table called "deleted_at" (maybe a deleted_by) as nullable.
Only return rows when deleted_at is null.

This is better for recording when and by whom data was deleted.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, ill try working with that. If i make it work, ill accept your answer. Sadly i need to do it in the bad way. I have very limited time. But thanks for telling me anyway.

Comment: @CodeProg, I have no idea what constraints you are under, but I will gladly assist you in implementing either solution. You can PM me with specifics if you want to.

Comment: I didnt even know that that was possible but i think ill take you up on your offer.

Comment: @MortenBork You've just published your personal email address on a public, searchable website. I would bet it's not long before the spam spiders find it and mail you junk forever and a day. If it was me I would delete that comment a.s.a.p.... anyway SO is meant to be a public repository of questions and answers for everyone to benefit from, it's not a place to solicit or offer private consultancy work, that's why there's no PM feature. You can use the chat feature to have an IM conversation but it's still public. If the OP asks a public question, they get a public answer.

Comment: The reason I used my email there, is because, it is a throw away email, that gets so spammed you wouldn't believe it. But I look every so often into. But thank you for your concern. I did not mean to solicit any work. I merely wanted to help him for free. He might not be able to publicly post enough info to be specific about his requirements.

Answer (score 0):

You have an integrity constraint issue meaning the id of the user has been used in another table and the table has a foreign key constraint on it.

Comment: Im sorry if it might seem like a trivial question but i have only worked with .net for 10 weeks in total... But how would you go about that? As said, i assume that it can be done through FluentAPI, but i im not very used to working with fluentApi

Comment: this describes the problem but doesn't actually provide a solution to it...

Comment: This is not a .net issue but rather a database schema issue. You can either cascade your delete, meaning whenever you delete the user, you also delete all the information linked to them. From an audit perspective, this is bad practice. The other option is to put an active indicator on the users table hence rather than deleting, you simply mark the user as in active